# Unity3d Split Texture2d at runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, split, runtime, texture2d

I am creating a mobile painting application. I have two textures (Texture2D), which is a template of an image and a color map for it.

This color map contains a unique color for each region of the template where the player can draw.

I need to have several other textures, one texture per each unique color in the color map.

For now I am trying to use GetPixels for the color map, and using a dictionary, I check every pixel.

If there is no color as a key value in this dictionary, create a new texture with SetPixel using the coordinate
If there is a color as a key, get the texture by using the key and SetPixel with the coordinates to get this texture.

But when I run this even my computer begins to extremely lag, no word about mobiles.

Is there a more efficent way?

To help you visualize the issue I am adding the color map, the texture I need to split.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a magically fast way to do it, but here are a few tips that may help:

- Try using GetPixels32 (and SetPixels32) instead of simply GetPixels - the return value is not Color but Color32 which uses bytes and not floating points, it should be faster. See http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels32.html http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels32.html
- Do not call SetPixel for each pixel, this is really slow. Instead, for each color create a temporary Color32 array and work with it, and only at the end assign all the arrays to new textures using SetPixels32.
- If you use foreach loop or Array.ForEach or some linq stuff to parse the colors array, don't do it - use simple for loop, it is the fastest way.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Now there is a faster way to do this, which is using [`Texture2D.GetRawTextureData()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetRawTextureData.html) and [`Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData.html).